# Shortcode IF statment help

Tags: theme-development, shortcode

Below is the code I have been working on to run a shortcode. I have tried implimenting an  `if()` statement, however nothing has worked.

I have two outputs. What I am looking to do, is if the attributes

```
('img', 'user', 'text')
```

are present in the shortcode, display `$output1`.

Otherwise, if the attributes

```
('img', 'text', 'length', 'material', 'power')
```

are present in the shortcode, display `$output2`.

```
function hire_equipment_func($atts) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'img' => '',
        'user' => '',
        'text' => '',
        'length' => '',
        'material' => '',
        'power' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    $atts = array_change_key_case((array)$atts, CASE_LOWER);

    return $output1;

    $output1 =

    '<div class="hire-equipment-item">

        <div class="hire-equipment-item-img"><img src="' . $atts['img'] . '" height=200px" width="200px" alt=""></div><br />

        <div class="hire-equipment-item-user">' . $atts['user'] . '</div>

        <div class="hire-equipment-item-text">' . $atts['text'] . '</div>

    </div>';

    $output2 =

    '<div class="hire-equipment-item">

        <div class="hire-equipment-item-img"><img src="' . $atts['img'] . '" height=200px" width="200px" alt=""></div><br />

        <div class="hire-equipment-item-user">' . $atts['user'] . '</div>

        <div class="hire-equipment-more-information">

            <table class="hire-equipment-more-information-table" cellpadding="15px">

                <tr>

                    <th>Length:</th>
                    <th>Material:</th>
                    <th>Power:</th>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td> ' . $atts['length'] . ' </td>
                    <td> ' . $atts['material'] . ' </td>
                    <td> ' . $atts['power'] . ' </td>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>

    </div>';

}
add_shortcode( 'hire_equipment', 'hire_equipment_func' );
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure I understand the question. You would like to display different markup depending on which fields are set in the `$atts` array? If this is the case, then this should work:

```
// Check so fields are set in the `$atts` array.
if (isset($atts['img'], $atts['user'], $atts['text'])) {
  return '<div class="hire-equipment-item">
            <div class="hire-equipment-item-img">
              <img src="' . esc_url($atts['img']) . '" height=200px" width="200px" alt="">
            </div><br />
            <div class="hire-equipment-item-user">' . $atts['user'] . '</div>
            <div class="hire-equipment-item-text">' . sanitize_text_field($atts['text']) . '</div>
         </div>';
} 
elseif (isset($atts['img'], $atts['text'], $atts['length'], $atts['material'], $atts['power'])) {
  // Second output goes here.
}
```

Notice that `user` may not be set in the second case else the first condition will always be true.

Since the markup for both conditions are very similar a better approach might be:

```
function hire_equipment_func($atts) {
  // Store merged result. 
  $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'img' => '',
    'user' => '',
    'text' => '',
    'length' => '',
    'material' => '',
    'power' => '',
  ), array_change_key_case($atts, CASE_LOWER));


  $output = '<div class="hire-equipment-item>';

  // Check if image should be appended to output.
  if (isset($atts['img'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="hire-equipment-item-img">
                  <img src="' . esc_url($attribs['img']) . '" height="200" width="200" alt="" />
                </div>';
  }
  // Check if user should be appended to output.
  if (isset($atts['user'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="hire-equipment-item-user">' . $atts['user'] . '</div>';
  }
  // Check if text should be appended to output.
  if (isset($atts['text'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="hire-equipment-item-text">' . $atts['text'] . '</div>';
  }
  // Check if we need to output more-information table.
  if (isset($atts['length']) || isset($atts['material']) || isset($atts['power'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="hire-equipment-more-information">
                 <table class="hire-equipment-more-information-table" cellpadding="15px">
                   <tr>
                     <th>Length:</th>
                     <th>Material:</th>
                     <th>Power:</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td> ' . (isset($atts['length']) ? $atts['length'] : '') . ' </td>
                     <td> ' . (isset($atts['material']) ? $atts['material'] : '') . ' </td>
                     <td> ' . (isset($atts['power']) ? $atts['power'] : '') . ' </td>
                   </tr>
                 </table>
               </div>';
  }
  $output .= '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```

You might also need to use some sanitazion for your output. For instance use `esc_url()` for urls and `sanitize_text_field()` for strings and so on.

Comment: I am attempting the code that you have provided. I will update you in a few minutes if it works! :D

Comment: I ran into a few errors in my code, but once I corrected all the errors, it worked! Thank you!!

Comment: @Jesse - Glad I could help, I think you should have a look on my second solution, since I think this should be more dynamic.

Comment: This is what I ended up with :) I may rework the code later to what you have specified above if need be, but at the moment, this issue was the last I had to my website.

https://jsfiddle.net/brzLhq4b/1/

Comment: @Jesse - I added an updated and hopefully working second solution =)